# Django database error on one to many relationship

Tags: django, datamodel

I created a data model in Django which has many to one relation (N topics to 1 user) like this:

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When I try to load the data model in the admin page, I get this error:

```
Exception Value:    
no such column: talk_comment.author_id
```

Did I miss something in the data model?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you sync your database after defining models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually modify/create the tables in database (manually, with `South` or `manage.py syncdb`).

Comment: I did syncdb once before I add the author field. How can I update the current database?

Comment: Drop the table and `syncdb` again; modify manually using SQL or use schema migrations with [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I just check my db and drop it manually. I will go use South from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the table with `syncdb` . you need to use [South Migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html)

Its really very good and you can even revert back to previous migration in case of some problem